# C question: error: expected ')' before '*' token

Tags: c, function, struct

**Edit 2**

Thanks for all the suggestions, I edited the code below from the suggestions given. However, it still doesnt seem to compile. But nevertheless, thanks a lot for the help hands.

**Edit**

I apologize for not putting the pcb struct into the code snippet. There is a struct called pcb defined in above the two structs I originally posted. Namely,

```
typedef struct pcb{
    UINT32 proc;
    struct pcb *link;
}pcb;
```

Hi,

I asked a question regarding structs in C a few minutes ago and got an answer blazing fast. But now I'm facing another problem, namely the error in the title of this question. I'm trying to implement a simple priority queue in C using arrays of queues. However, when I try to declare a function on pcb_pQ structure, I get the above error. I have the structs clearly defined in the heard file.

In the header file:

```
typedef struct pcb_Q{
    pcb *head;
    pcb *tail;
    SINT32 size;
} pcb_Q;

typedef struct pcb_pQ {
 pcb_Q queues[5];
 SINT32 size;
} pcb_pQ;
```

Function prototype in header file:

```
/*priority queue operations*/
VOID pcb_pq_enqueue(pcb_pQ*, pcb*);
```

Function impelmentation in .c file:

```
VOID pcb_pq_enqueue(pcb_pQ* pcb_pQ_p, pcb* pcb_p) {
 pcb_Q* pcb_Q_p;
 int priority;

 priority = pcb->proc_priority;
 pcb_Q_p = &pcb_pQ->queues[priority];

 pcb_enqueue(pcb_Q_p, pcb);
}
```

When I try to compile the above code, I get an "error: expected ')' before '*' token". This error is pointing to the function signature in the .c file, namely

```
VOID pcb_pq_enqueue(pcb_pQ* pcb_pQ_p, pcb* pcb_p) {
```

But I am not sure why I am getting this error, could someone give me a hand? Thanks a lot.

Comment: where is pcb defined as type?

Comment: I consider it a very bad idea to use the same name for types and variables. It'll be a lot easier to read if you distinguish them.

Comment: it seems from the comments that the compiler cant find pcb_pQ, because I have other functions that use pcb and pcb_Q and they don't show any issues. is there anything like maximum number of structs defined per header? i know it sounds stupid, but i just dont know whats wrong

Comment: and if i take out the pcb_pQ in the function parameter, the code comiples fine

Comment: @lhw What compiler are you using?

Comment: @paxdiablo - its funny that until today I actually thought using type names as variable names was illegal, probably because I had never attempted it ... in nearly 20 years of using C :)

Comment: its a cross compiler for the m68k coldfire board, i dont know the exact specs of it though, i really dont want to dig through specs but i may have to

Comment: @lhw, just for fun, rename the variables in your function so they're different to the types. It'll at least rule out that as a potential problem with your cross-compiler.

Comment: i already tried it ;) no luck

Comment: Okay, try naming the struct: typedef struct **pcb** { UINT32 proc; struct pcb *link; } pcb;

Comment: no luck, but i really do appreciate all the suggestions. thanks a lot

Comment: @lhw - I think something _other_ than your code is broken. Can you post more details regarding your compiler? Someone who has worked on that (or similar) board might have solved this. I really am starting to think your compiler is broken.

Comment: You've shown us several code snippets, but it's not at all clear where or in what order they appear. Can you show us a single source file that exhibits the problem? (Using a `typedef` name that hasn't yet been defined as a `typedef` commonly causes syntax errors.)

Answer (score 2):

Are you including the header file? Barring misspellings, that error is almost invariably caused by a missing typedef.

In other words, the compiler doesn't know about either the `pcb_pQ` or `pcb` type (or both).

---

*Edit:* There's something else wrong because this compiles fine:

```
qq.h
    typedef struct pcb {
        unsigned int proc;
        struct pcb *link;
    } pcb;

    typedef struct{
        pcb *head;
        pcb *tail;
        int size;
    } pcb_Q;

    typedef struct pcb_pQ {
        pcb_Q queues[5];
        int size;
    } pcb_pQ;

    void pcb_pq_enqueue(pcb_pQ*, pcb*);

qq.c:
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include "qq.h"
    void pcb_pq_enqueue(pcb_pQ *pcb_pQ, pcb *pcb) {}
    int main (void) { return 0; }
```

I had to use other types (and I modified the `pcb` structure to be a named one - I'm not sure your given one should have compiled since as-is since there is no `struct pcb` type in existence).

---

Based on all the comments and answers to date, I'm pretty certain there's something wrong with your compiler. GCC compiles that snippet above just fine.

Try putting my two files above onto your system and seeing if they compile okay.

And be aware that you *do* need to name your `pcb` structure. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895209/how-is-it-legal-to-reference-an-undefined-type-inside-a-structure) for the gory details but the consensus seems to be that

```
    typedef struct {
        unsigned int proc;
        struct pcb *link;
    } pcb;
```

will define a `struct pcb` incomplete type which is a distinct type from `pcb` (and the structure you're currently defining).

Comment: Did you notice the caps in the code he pasted, in particular VOID and UINT32?

Comment: thanks for trying it out, now im thinking it may be a compiler issue.. i am using a cross-compiler, not the usual gcc.

Comment: @Tim, I noticed that but, if they weren't declared properly, he would have gotten an error in the header file, not the C file.

Comment: @paxdiablo, Sorry, I did not catch the prototype.

Comment: Compiled fine for me too, under gcc and clang, surprisingly leaving pcb unnamed didn't give any warnings. @lhw does this give you any errors when using your cross compiler?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the compiler doesn't find the defintion of `pcb`.

Answer (score 0):

First, it is '**void**' not '**VOID**' until or unless you have definition like

```
#define VOID void
```

This can be better if

```
typedef struct tag_struct_pcb_Q {
    pcb *head;
    pcb *tail;
    SINT32 size;
} pcb_Q;

typedef struct tag_structpcb_pQ {
 pcb_Q queues[5];
 SINT32 size;
} pcb_pQ;
```

modern 'C' compiler expect the return type must be mentioned.

If you have definition like this also cause error.

```
#define VOID
```

Another possibility

VOID pcb_pq_enqueue(pcb_pQ* pcb_pQ, **pcb*** pcb) {

where does **pcb** is from? it is not good to have **pcb* pcb**. ALWAYS give different name for variable type and variable name

Comment: yes it actually is defined in another definition file, thanks for the answer though

Comment: I saw the same thing at first, however, he's getting the error when compiling the c file. If `VOID` was broken, he would have gotten the error in the header as soon as it saw the function prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
typedef struct{
    UINT32 proc;
    struct pcb *link;
}pcb;
```

to:

```
typedef struct pcb {
    UINT32 proc;
    struct pcb *link;
} pcb;
```

Comment: Why wouldn't that throw an error in the header, though? I think he may have a broken compiler.