# Struct Has Function Pointer with Argument Of Parent Struct Type

Tags: c, struct, function-pointers, typedef

I am trying to define a struct type (call it ***thing***) that has a function pointer in it (call it ***bar***), and I want that function to take an argument that is a pointer to an object of type ***thing***.

I know from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62957815/2233633) that I can either do a forward declaration or declare the struct type in the argument list of the function pointer as shown here:

```
// In header

typedef struct thing thing_type;

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;

    double (*bar)(thing_type *t)
} thing;
```

***OR***

```
// In header
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;

    double (*bar)(struct thing *t)
} thing;
```

But when I go to initialize these values, I always get an incompatible pointer type warning.

```
double bar1(thing *t);
double bar2(thing *t);

// In main()

thing foo = {1, 2, bar1}; // WARNING
```

> initialization of ‘double (*)(struct thing *)’ from incompatible
> pointer type ‘double (*)(thing *)’ [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

```
foo.bar = bar2; // WARNING
```

> passing argument 1 of ‘foo->bar’ from incompatible pointer type
> [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

My code works the way I intend it to as far as I can tell through testing, but I would like to understand if I am doing anything "wrong" here or if there is a way to do what I want without throwing warnings for every assignment.

*Note that thing foo = {1, 2, **&bar1** }; (passing the address of a function pointer) makes no difference for this warning.*

Comment: `double (*bar)(struct thing *t)` Neither of your examples has a structure called `struct thing`. They have a type called `thing` but that is not the same as `struct thing`.

Comment: OK, @kaylum but if I define the functions as with `struct thing` argument types and try to actually use those structs in the function, like

 `double bar1(struct thing *t) = { return (double)( t->a + t->b) }`
then I get an error:
`pointer to incomplete class type "struct thing" is not allowed`. I guess I should say that the function bar needs to be able to access attributes of the struct.

Comment: You don't have a complete `struct thing` type anywhere. That's the point. You can't dereference a type that you have not completely defined. If you aren't convinced about that then please tell us which lines of code define `struct thing`.

Comment: @kaylum, Is `struct thing` not defined in 
`typedef struct
{ int a; int b; double (*bar)(struct thing *t) } thing;` ?

Comment: No it isn't. That is an unnamed struct that is typedefed to thing.

Comment: Nope. That defines a type called `thing` which is not the same as `struct thing`. Try: `typedef stuct thing { .. } thing;`

Comment: In C, struct tags are in a separate namespace.

Comment: Thanks guys, I knew I was missing something pretty fundamental. Glad I asked!

Comment: I wish people first learned to use structs without typedefs, because *this is always possible*. If typedefs are used to "type less", I consider this reason to be largely invalid. The two valid reasons I would accept are: 1) hiding types in an API, and 2) reducing complexity with function pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this code:

```
typedef struct thing thing_type;

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;

    double (*bar)(thing_type *t)
} thing;
```

the first `typedef` defines `thing_type` to be an alias for `struct thing`, and the second `typedef` defines `thing` to be an alias for a structure with no tag. This second alias, `thing`, has no relationship with the first alias, `thing_type`, or with its structure type, `struct thing`. In particular, there is no connection between the two types `thing` and `struct thing`.

Similarly, in this code:

```
typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;

    double (*bar)(struct thing *t)
} thing;
```

the `typedef` defines `thing` to be an alias for a structure with no tag, and `bar` is declared to be a pointer to a function with a parameter type of `struct thing *`. Again, there is no connection between the two types `thing` and `struct thing`.

To refer to the same structure type in multiple places, you must use a tag for it. This is as simple as:

```
// Use the structure tag while defining the structure:
typedef struct MyTag
{
    int a;
    int b;
    double (*bar)(struct MyTag *);
} MyAlias;
```

or:

```
// Define an alias first, then the structure definition can use the alias:
typedef struct MyTag MyAlias;
struct MyTag
{
    int a;
    int b;
    double (*bar)(MyAlias *);
};
```